# Javascript Set delete method syntax

Tags: javascript, set, string-interpolation, template-literals

In working with a `new Set` as opposed to a `new Array`, because the Set handles duplicate entries well, I struggled with the syntax passed using the `delete()` method. This would apply to other methods but my problem primarily pertained to the `delete()` method in this case.

In passing a constant to the `delete()` Set method the response was false even though the Set was built from the same Array data.

In outputting the set to the console the objects were as follows:

```
Set(12) {'10165', '122', '88', '884', '10224', …}
```

I was finding that if I hardcoded the object value `console.log(someSet.delete('122'));` the `delete()` method would return `true` and the object was successfully deleted from the Set.

However, if I referenced a constant `console.log(someSet.delete(someConst.id));` the `delete()` method would return `false` even though it was the same value as the hardcoded version indicated above.

With some experimentation, the following occurred:

```
console.log(someSet.delete(someConst.id)); // false, value passed 122
console.log(someSet.delete("'"+someConst.id+"'")); // false, value passed '122' (same as hardcoded value)
console.log(someSet.delete('"'+someConst.id+'"')); // false, value passed "122"
console.log(someSet.delete(`'${someConst.id}'`)); // false, value passed '122' (same as hardcoded value)
console.log(someSet.delete(`${someConst.id}`)); // true, value passed 122 (different than hard coded value)
```

Why is it that variable interpolation with template literals (backtick) resulted in `true` where the direct reference to the constant resulted in `false`?
Why is it that the hardcoded value `'122'` resulted in `true` where `122` from the interpolated var/const also resulted in `true`.

```
console.log(someSet.delete(someConst.id)); // false
console.log(someSet.delete(`${someConst.id}`)); // true
```

Do Set methods check data type as part of the usage even though a Set can hold any value of any data type?

Even though using interpolation for the var/const proved successful I wanted to understand why.

Comment: Because the string `200` and the number `200` are different things.

Comment: @tkausl thanks for the response. I've corrected the values in the original post to be in line with the actual object values. 
Assuming `'122'` was presented as a string are you saying `delete(`${someConst.id}`)` resulted in a string as well where `delete(someConst.id)` is a Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set`s use the SameValueZero algorithm to determine equality. According to this, strings and numbers are never equal (since they are of different types). Since your set is storing strings, you have to pass strings to `delete`.

To convert a number to a string, you can concatenate it with an empty string, use the `String` function, or call `.toString`:

```js
someSet.delete('' + someConst.id);
someSet.delete(String(someConst.id));
someSet.delete(someConst.id.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

`'122'`, or `"122"`, or  `122` are strings. So when you run:

```
console.log(122 === '122');
```

You will get false.

If you want to convert your number to string consider converting it by using [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

You can do:

```
console.log(`${someConst.id}`);
```

Which will "put your number inside an empty string, resulting a string".

Or, use `String()`

```
console.log(String(someConst.id));
```

Also, check these examples using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```js
console.log(typeof 122);
console.log(typeof "122");
console.log(typeof '122');
console.log(typeof "122");
console.log(typeof `${122}`);

console.log(122 === '122');
```

Answer (score 0):

The set contains String `200`.

It does not contain `someConst.id`, which is Number 200.
It does not contain `"'"+someConst.id+"'"`, which is String `'200'`. The single quotes are part of the string.
It does not contain `'"'+someConst.id+'"'`, which is String `"200"`. The double quotes are part of that string.

Similarly `'${someConst.id}'` includes the single quotes in the string.

Only the template literal resolves to String `200`.